# How to not allow inspect element or CTRL-U in HTML

Tags: html

for a website, I would like to not allow for `CTRL-U` or inspect element on chrome browser. I have seen webpages with it, and I would like to be able to do it on my web page. How can I do this (HTML5 is acceptable too.)

Answer (score 1):

this bit of javascript worked for me:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 85 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(("ctrl-u pressed!"))  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Was this in the head or in the body. (Could you give me some context in the code?)

Comment: that was in the <body>. (I ran it in chrome's console)